# jQuery dataTables fnDraw() not re-drawing table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a static HTML table that contains prices and descriptions of parts from various suppliers.

The table contains a column of text boxes for a user to enter a quantity against a particular part, the idea being that it then calculates the price across the suppliers so they can see the cheapest one.

I have some logic in the dataTables fnFooterCallback function that generates the total, so I am trying to get the table to redraw (and so update the totals in the footer) when the value of the quantity texboxes change.

I have a blur() handler registered on the inputs that calls fnDraw() on the table, but it does not seem to be doing anything.

I've re-created an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qp492/3/), and here is the Javascript:

```
var $productsTable = $("table#products").dataTable({
    bFilter: false,
    bPaginate: false,
    bSort: false,
    bInfo: false,
    fnFooterCallback: function (nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
        // For every column after the qty and desc colums
        for (var column = 2; column < aaData[0].length; column++) {
            var columnTotal = 0;

            // Sum every row into a column total
            for (var row = 0; row < aaData.length; row++) {
                var quantity = aaData[row][0].value || 0;
                columnTotal += aaData[row][column] * quantity;
            }

            // * and / by 100 to round to 2 decimals
            nRow.cells[column].innerText = Math.round(columnTotal * 100) / 100; 
        }
    }
});

$("input[data-qty]").blur(function () {
    // Example at http://datatables.net/api indicates that this should be enough?
    $productsTable.fnDraw();
});​
```

Can anyone can tell me where I am going wrong, please?

Thank you.

Comment: While experimenting I added a fnDrawCallback() to the DataTable that just calls alert(), and that is indeed being called, so fnDraw() is being called.  Looks like the problem is with "var quantity = aaData[row][0].value || 0;" always evaluating to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your code `aaData[row][0].value` doesn't return anything. You can try to keep an array and set total values from there. In the `blur` event you must set the appropriate value for each of the textboxes. Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qp492/6/) to the modified code.

Comment: Thank you, Karlen.  That's perfect.